# Should integers be included in the strings.xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, hardcode

If I have a button with an attribute of

```
    android:text="+1"
```

should it be included in the @string file or is it fine to be hardcoded in the activity_main?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can include them in the `strings.xml`(if being treated as strings , otherwise you should save them with `<integer>` tag). You don't need to explicitly put them in layout.

**If being treated as strings** (As in your case , you are setting it as string)

```
<string name="my_integer_value">3</string>
```

So it is accessible as `android:text="@string/my_integer_value"`

**If being treated as Integers**

```
<integer name="my_integer_value">3</integer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what the string is being used for.  `strings.xml` is for UI strings that may be different in different configurations, most commonly different locales/languages.  String constants that are meaningful to the app should generally not be in `strings.xml`.

Since this string is a button label, it should probably go in `strings.xml`.